# im tryng to install wine in ubuntu 22.04 but im getting malformed entry 1 in list file

Tags: installation, wine

I'm trying to install wine in ubuntu 22.04 but I'm getting malformed entry 1 in list file. Here is the error code: malformed entry 1 in list file /ect/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_ld_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_bionic-jammy.list

Comment: The solution is to remove the malformed list by typing: sudo rm  /ect/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_ld_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_bionic-jammy.list

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove the malformed list by typing:

```
sudo rm /ect/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_ld_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_bionic-jammy.list
```